# How to generate an authorization code using PayPal-Ruby-SDK for future payment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

I am trying to generate access token for paypal for future payment using  PayPal-Ruby-SDK [example](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK/blob/master/spec/payments_examples_spec.rb#L149).

```
it "Exchange Authorization Code for Refresh / Access Tokens" do
    # put your authorization code for testing here
    auth_code = ''
    if auth_code != ''
      access_token  = FuturePayment.exch_token(auth_code)
      access_token.should_not be_nil
    end
end
```

It requires an authorization code which I am unable to find how to generate.
Any Help will be highly obliged.

Comment: I have the same question, any luck here?

Comment: It's already mid 2019 and their API are still not clear, any news?

Answer (score 1):

You are able to get Authorization Code only via PayPal web login flow. According to [Paypal's official documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/auth-headers/) .

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. You have to make API calls to create reference transactions:

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-REST-API-issues/issues/44

Scroll to the bottom of that issue - looks like at least they're offering some kind of limited access to a REST API so you can skip their SOAP stuff.

Answer (score -1):

The authorization code is part of your application details that were provided to you when you registered your application at [developer.paypal.com](http://developer.paypal.com/), and you can view your application there to get the code.